# Compute primes with multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading

I am trying to understand threading. I am trying to have multiple threads compute primes. I want one thread to compute the first number then have the next thread compute the next number and so forth then whichever thread finds the prime print it.

So, start with 1 to 50. pass a new number toa new thread. I think thats what we want.

Heres what i have so far.

```
void* compute_prime (void* arg)
{
//pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
int candidate = 2;
int n = *((int*) arg);

while (1) {
int factor;
int is_prime = 1;

/* Test primality by successive division.  */
for (factor = 2; factor < candidate; ++factor)
  if (candidate % factor == 0) {
    is_prime = 0;
    break;
  }
/* Is this the prime number we're looking for?  */
if (is_prime) {
  if (--n == 0)
    /* Return the desired prime number as the thread return value.  */

    return (void*) candidate;
}
++candidate;
}

return NULL;
}




int main ()
{
int which_prime = 50;
int isPrime1, isPrime2, isPrime3, isPrime4;
fprintf (stderr, "main thread pid is %d\n", (int) getpid ());
for(master_list; master_list < which_prime; master_list++)
{
//do{

// pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); 

pthread_create (&thread1, NULL, &compute_prime, &master_list);
//master_list++;
//pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

//}while(master_list < which_prime);

}

return 0;
}
```

my output.

```
main thread pid is 508
Thread1 Found the prime number:  3.
Thread2 Found the prime number:  3.
Thread3 Found the prime number:  3.
Thread4 Found the prime number:  3.
Thread1 Found the prime number:  7.
Thread2 Found the prime number:  7.
Thread3 Found the prime number:  7.
Thread4 Found the prime number:  7.
Thread1 Found the prime number:  13.
Thread2 Found the prime number:  13.
Thread3 Found the prime number:  13.
Thread4 Found the prime number:  13.
```

etc....

Which is somewhat what i want. But not every thread should find the same prime. They should be finding different primes. Even if i increment the variable before the thread it still wont work. I commented out the code that i tried to get it to work. what do i need to do? I hope i was clear.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerating primes is not *embarassingly parallel* which means that it's not trivial to decompose the problem into independent computations.  Sieves and trial divisions require (or at least are vastly improved by) previous prime number history.

I'm sure there is serious research on the topic of parallel prime computation.  Off the top of my head I would suggest you rely on a [probabilistic prime test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) which you can run in parallel on many numbers.  This will greatly filter the set of numbers you need to test with some other mechanism (such as trial division, as your code already uses).

If you really want to do trial divisions with *all* numbers lower than your candidate (rather than just the primes, as would be more typical and vastly more efficient) then I suggest for `N` threads you have each thread start `candidate` at a different base (3, 5, 7, ...) and each thread increments `candidate` by `2*N` so they all hit a unique set of numbers (you are currently starting at 2 and incrementing by 1, but I am assuming you will eventually realize that even numbers are never prime...)

Comment: You only need to know the first `k` prime numbers to determine if numbers from `k+1` to `k*k` are prime; and therefore all numbers from `k+1` to `k*k` can be tested in parallel (e.g. divide `(k*k) - (k+1)` by the number of threads/CPUs to determine how many numbers each thread should test). This means `k` would follow the sequence `2, 4, 16, 256, 65536, ...`; and you'd have more than enough work happening in parallel after the first few iterations. Should be easy to adapt this to a sieve too.

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to your question is that you're passing in the *address* of the master_list integer.  This means that all the threads are looking in the same location to figure out what n is.  So, even when you lock, increment, unlock, it isn't surprising the threads all behave similarly.  Try allocating an array of ints, and have each thread look at a separate element.  That should hopefully eliminate the duplicates.

That being said, even if you make that change, there's a lot that can be improved.  See Ben Jackson's answer for a good description of the bigger picture.